# CloudFormation pass tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to have an option to pass to my CFT tags so I could tag S3 bucket that I am creating and that it will not be mandatory - to have default value. How ever I cannot find any parameter type that will do the trick

Comment: What do you mean by ` that I am creating and that it will not be mandatory - to have default value` ?  You want to have the option to pass the values of the tags as blank if there are not set?

Comment: i want that the cloud formation will have default value in case user dont pass the tags parameter

Comment: Did you check out my answer? you found it helpfull ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to set a default value to cloudformation parameters, you need to use the `Default` attribute when you define the parameter.

The following template snippet creates S3 Bucket and add the relevant tag(single one!) based on user input :

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Create S3 Bucket with relevant tags
Parameters:
  S3TagKey:
    Description: The S3 Tag key
    Type: String
    Default: Your Default key
  S3TagValue:
    Description: The S3 Tag Value
    Type: String
    Default: Your Default Value
Resources:
  ExampleS3:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      BucketName: s3-name
      Tags:
        - Key: !Ref S3TagKey
          Value: !Ref S3TagValue
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
        IgnorePublicAcls: true
        RestrictPublicBuckets: true
```

When you click on `create stack` you will be asked to provide the key-value pair values, As you can see the default values are set already. In case you want to change the tags, just update the relevant field.

[image]

Results :

[image]